# [NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10f8c6fc0' swift 4 iOS

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode10

I am fetching data from the model in this way

```
if let birthdate = personInfo?.str_Birthdate {
    cell.dobTF.text = birthdate
}
```

But app crash and return this error

> '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10f8c6fc0'

Comment: It looks like `str_Birthdate` is `NSNull`,  not a string instance. Where did the value come from?

Comment: please, show from where comes value for `str_Birthdate`

Comment: Basically str_Birthdate have nsnull value but don't know how can handle it

Comment: @EneaDume it is objective c Model nsstring property . And i this not have value but problem is how can add check of nsnull value on it.

Comment: crash on if if let birthdate = personInfo?.str_Birthdate

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting here is `NSNull`. It is an object representing `null` in context of objective-C arrays and dictionaries. Specifically in JSONs it distinguishes between receiving field `(null)` instead of not receiving a field at all. In your case I assume this value is force-unwrapped as a string so the error is a bit late. Please try the following:

```
if let dateObject = personInfo?.str_Birthdate {
    if let nullObject = dateObject as? NSNull {
        // A field was returned but is (null)
    } else if let stringObject = dateObject as? String {
        cell.dobTF.text = stringObject
    } else {
        // Unknown object
    }
} else {
    // This field is missing
}
```

You can actually just convert all `NSNull` instances to `nil` using something like:

```
func removeNSNullInstancesFrom(_ item: Any?) -> Any? {
    guard let item = item else { return nil }
    if let _ = item as? NSNull {
        return nil
    } else if let array = item as? [Any] {
        return array.compactMap { removeNSNullInstancesFrom($0) }
    } else if let dictionary = item as? [String: Any] {
        var newDict: [String: Any] = [String: Any]()
        dictionary.forEach { item in
            guard let value = removeNSNullInstancesFrom(item.value) else { return }
            newDict[item.key] = value
        }
        return newDict
    } else {
        return item
    }
}
```

You can use this on the whole response object or a specific item. In your case you can do: `cell.dobTF.text = removeNSNullInstancesFrom(birthdate)`.

But this method should in general recursively remove all `NSNull` instances from fields, arrays and dictionaries which are standard for JSON.

Comment: One of the nice examples where type inference leads to unwanted behaviour.